# Надо разобратся с метками на тему [асинхронность]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

На тему асинхронности меток у нас много:

- [async](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async) (402 вопроса)
- [await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/await) (31 вопрос)
- [async-await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) (537 вопросов)
- [async-programming](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-programming) (95 вопросов)
- [асинхронность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) (292 вопроса)

Итак:

Очевидно, что [async-programming](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-programming) -> [асинхронность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

И, может быть всё остальное туда же.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синонимизировано и объединено:

- [await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/await) → [async-await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await)
- [async](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async) и [async-programming](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-programming) → [асинхронность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: А разве [tag:async-await] это не [tag:асинхронность]?

Comment: @wchistow нет, ключевые слова async и await это реализация асинхронного подхода с помощью машины состояний, предоставляющей возможность писать асинхронный код, похожий визуально на синхронный, современная альтернатива континуациям (цепочки .then, .ContinueWith и т.д.). А сама по себе асинхронность это система ожиданий. То есть термин асинхронность можно поставить рядом с многопоточностью по значимости. Полноценный асинхронный код можно писать и без async/await на голых колбэках или цепочках, просто выглядеть он будет в этом случае пострашнее. Поэтому это разное.